# Two DIVs disappearing in Safari 5.1 on Mac - gone from source code

Tags: css, macos, html, safari

Having trouble figuring out why a div disappears in Safari on a Mac.  It works fine in Firefox on the same Mac.  Also works fine in Chrome, etc.  When I look at the source code in Safari, that divs are simply not there.

There ones disappearing are #sf-wrapper and #menu-donate.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

http://www.lungcancerfoundation.org/

Comment: You're including a PHP page as a stylesheet. You should check that out, it could be running all sorts of crap.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Yule.  I don't think that file is to blame, though.  It's associated with a WordPress plugin and has been running on the site for a long time without incident.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Which DIVs are disappearing in Safari on the Mac? I looked at it in Safari on my PC and it seems to render fine. Can you link to screenshots of the site in FF and then one of the site in Mac's Safari so we can see?

Best,

Cynthia